# Execution frequency of AudioKit RawDataTap is lower than expected after update (5.4.1 -> 5.6)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

Demo project [here](https://github.com/anytwopoints/RawDataTapBugDemo). This will need to be run on an actual device.

This looks to be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108769/audiokit-tap-skips-over-time-intervals).

In AudioKit 5.4.1 the doHandleTapBlock method is executed reliably at the frequency specified by the bufferSize (ie once every 256 frames if bufferSize is 256).

After updating to 5.6 doHandleTapBlock is instead executed once every 4410 frames or once every 100ms) - on my device at least.

In the project above I've subclassed RawDataTap to show the AVAudioTime frames elapsed between executions.

If one instead uses AVFoundation installTap the behaviour is identical (again, see the demo project) unless one sets the frameLength for each buffer to the bufferSize (if one does this the elapsed time is equal to the bufferLength as expected), so I'm assuming this is what's not getting done here! The documentation for AVAudioPCMBuffer does also say this [property needs to be set before the buffer is used](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiopcmbuffer/1386069-framelength).

Setting the bufferLength from within the doHandleTapBlock method doesn't solve the issue however.

Looking at the new code for BaseTap it looks as though the buffer is now copied to a bufferWithCapacity variable within the handleTapBlock method, and subsequently the frameLength is set for this rather than the original buffer... possibly the frameLength for the original buffer is therefore never set and therefore the frameCapacity is used instead to determine update rate?

I can just use installTap instead but I thought this was worth raising.